# How to connect windows 10 64 bit laptop with windows 7 32 bit laptop?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, 32-vs-64-bit

I want to connect my windows 10 laptop of 64 bit architecture with my another windows 7 laptop of 32 bit architecture. I turned the network visibility ON for all networks on both the laptops and changed the IPv4 settings to 192.168.1.1 and gateway to 192.168.1.2. The values are reversed for the other laptop for the same configuration. After that I see my another laptop in My Computer -> Network but am not able to send files between either. I have turned ON file sharing on both the systems.

Can anyone suggest any other file transfer methods (not any software) or modifications in my arrangements above to send files between my two laptops? \

P.S. - Please answer keeping in mind that I want to transfer large files and I have other means of transferring the files as well. It's just that I want to test and know other methods.

Comment: Depending on how big the files, you may hit a limit at or around 2GB, based on the 32-bit architecture on your Win7 PC, and that could be the determining factor in your strategy. It also depends on the nature of the files. If it's one big archive file, you may manage to upload it to your Win7 PC, but if it's, say, a video that's actually the film itself, encapsulated with subtitles and the like, that may not work. You need to tell us more about your network setup too. Can you hook both PCs via an Ethernet cable, with or without Ethernet-to-USB adapter? Do you do it over WiFi? All that...

Comment: Try the following method to share files.  Make sure Network Discovery, File / Print Sharing, and Password protected sharing are enabled on both computers.   If you wish to share by computer name, put an entry in the HOSTS file with the name and IP address of the computer you are trying to connect to. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP and make sure Wireless connections are Private.  Home Group was removed, so you cannot use that.
After all the above changes restart and test.

Comment: @Didier Why would there be a 2GB file size transfer limit?  AnshumanRanjan If one of the PCs has a 10/100 ethernet port, a crossover cable is required or the pinout on an existing patch [regular ethernet cable] must be switched _(1Gbit network cards auto-negotiate, so crossover cable isn't required)_